# Basic question about dimensionality of Euclidean group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I have a basic question about the dimensionality of the Euclidean group.
Why are degrees of freedom greater than the dimension? I thought that a degree of freedom is the same as a dimension, as in, $x\;\text{-}\;y$ plane is of dimension $2$ and therefore has $2$ degrees of freedom. Right?

So I don't understand how the degrees of freedom of the Euclidean group $E(n)$, defined by:

$$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

turn out to be greater than the dimension $n$.

For example, for dimension $n=2,$ the degrees of freedom are $3$, and for dimension $n=6$, the degrees of freedom are $n=3$.

I don't understand this. Please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have $2$ degree of freedom to move a point. The dimension is two. But the dimension of the group of isometries is the the degree of freedom to move from an isometry to another isometry. Having an isometry of the plane you can move to another isometry by changing a bit the translation part (that gives us two degrees of freedom), and changing a bit the rotation part, which gives us the remaining degree of freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, each Euclidean transformation (an element of $E(n)$) has the form $Ax+b$ where $A\in O(n)$ (an orthogonal matrix) and $b\in R^n$. Clearly, $b$ depends on $n$ parameteris and we just have to compute the dimension of $O(n)$. Orthogonality of a matrix means that each column is a unit vector and any two distinct columns are orthogonal. Thus, you have $n^2$ variables (entries of the matrix) and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ equations. By subtracting, this leaves you with  $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ parameters for the orthogonal group $O(n)$. (This argument sounds like cheating but there is a way to justify it using implicit function theorem.) Now, you get
$$
n+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}= \frac{n(n+1)}{2},
$$ 
for the dimension of $E(n)$, which is the number you found somewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks +1. What is $x$ an element of? would you write $x \in R$? I'm new to group theory, so this is a pretty basic question. thanks.

Comment: x is a vector in $R^n$.